# Samsung Galaxy Ace stuck on boot after failed rooting attempt

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-ace

I've been formatting my Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT-S5839i) and it worked pretty well. Then for some reason, I tried to root it, which I failed, and now my phone won't turn on anymore. It just stays on the boot logo (the one where Samsung GALAXY Ace is printed) and it never goes any further. Before my phone stopped working, I tried to install some "ClockWorkMod", and I guess I didn't follow the steps as I should've.

I can access the recovery menu, but each time I tried to just wipe data/factory reset or wipe cache partition, it didn't help, so right now I'm stuck with a non-working phone. I can still put files on the SD card. I just don't know how to go back to the Gingerbread version I had before.

So I'd like to know if anyone can offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have had ROM manager before, then you can install any ROM which you will find on different sites.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP on [the 2nd revision of the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/60240/2),

> I kept searching and I found a guide about ODIN and flashing the phone, and it worked very well! My phone is now working like it never died!
>
> You can find the guide I followed right [here](http://www.phonandroid.com/forum/rom-officielle-francaise-samsung-galaxy-ace-s5839i-sans-operateur-t58111.html) (The guide is in french, but if you look for flashing a phone with Odin, I think you can find a guide in English)